# Error with MaxMind geo2ip in Weblogic 12.2.1 and Maven

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c, maxmind

In Eclipse IDE, when I try to publish a JavaEE web app in weblogic server using geo2ip API, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:193)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.startModule(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1178)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:843)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1452)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:944)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:735)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.CoreXMLDeserializers$Std overrides final method deserialize.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:95)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.CoreXMLDeserializers$Std overrides final method deserialize.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1110)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1043)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1035)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:493)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:470)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.BasicResourceLoader.classForName(BasicResourceLoader.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadClass(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:97)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createClasses(BeanDeployment.java:203)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.initialize(WeldInjectionContainer.java:94)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:80)
```

My depency hierarchy in the pom.xml is:

```
[INFO] project:project:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.maxmind.db:maxmind-db:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] +- net.bootsfaces:bootsfaces:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
```

I've tried excluding the com.fasterxml.jackson dependency from the geo2ip dependency, but it didn't work either. I researched a lot for this problem but I cant find anyone else that has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a dependency conflict. Weblogic likely requires an older version of Jackson while `geoip2` requires a recent version. You could try switching to an older version of `geoip2` such as `2.4.0`, which should work with older versions of Jackson.

Comment: I tried using version 2.4.0, even with version 2.1.0, but the same error keeps appearing.

Comment: When you excluded the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` dependency in `geoip2`, did you get the same error or some other error from `geoip2` itself?